# Wrong datetime information

Tags: python, datetime

I have the string `"5-11-2019"` in **DAY/MONTH/YEAR** format, and am doing the following to increment 1 day:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str("5-11-2019"), '%d-%M-%Y') + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

However, instead of getting the result of `2019-11-06`, Python returns `2019-01-06`, removing 10 months, which I cannot for the life of me understand.

Answer (score 1):

You used `%d-%M-%Y` as format, but `%M` stands for `minute`, not `month`. You should use `%d-%m-%Y` (lower `m`).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `%m` instead of `%M`

```
%m = Months
%M = Minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the “%M”.

Also keep in mind that

%d = Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
and
**%-d** = Day of the month as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
[From https://strftime.org/]

So either pad your days with 0 or use “%-d”.